# Retrieve angular ng-repeat scope outside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat select element, which is formed from the MySQL table, problem is - can't output scope parameter outside of the ng-repeat of the selected option.

What I tried doing:

```
<select ng-model="rec_name">
     <option value=" ">Select</option>
     <option ng-selected="{{rec_name == item}}"  ng-repeat="item in tasks" value="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
<div>Operator is: {{rec_name}}</div>
```

Basically, it's almost what I need, but it only shows the value="{{item.name}}" in the Operator div field; which is logically understandable.

Thought, that simply making the equivalence of item and rec_name will allow me to do something like

```
<div>Operator is: {{rec_name.param}}</div>
```

Again, what am I trying to do is to output the `task.param` of currently selected option,formed from tasks, in the isolated from `ng-repeat div`.

How do I call other item parameters?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manually handle the click event.

Use the following code

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selecteditem"
        ng-options="selecteditem as selecteditem.brand for selecteditem in dropdownval">

                </select>
<div>Operator is: {{clicked_rec_name}}</div>


Have the following method in your controller

$scope.getClickedItem=function(item)
{
        $scope.clicked_rec_name=item.rec_name;
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/j51llTUoQ2IdAwUkTFc3?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this:

```
<select ng-model="rec_name">
                <option value=" ">Select</option>
                <option ng-selected="{{rec_name == item}}"  ng-repeat="item in tasks" value="{{item.name}}">
<a href="#" ng-click="rec_name == item">
                            {{item.name}}
                        </a>
</option>
</select>
<div>Operator is: {{rec_name}}</div>
```

Cheers:)